# Solve the linear systems together by reducing the appropriate augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Solve the linear systems together by reducing the appropriate augmented matrix:
> \begin{align*}
> x_1 - 5x_2 &= b_1 \\
> 3x_1 + 2x_2 &= b_2 \\
> \end{align*}
> where (i) $b_1 = 1$, $b_2 = 4$, (ii) $b_1 = -2$, $b_2 = 5$.

Would someone please kindly help me understand how to solve this question? This is my first post so cannot upload photo. But apparently the link will work.

[Editor's note: original picture can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umajY.jpg)]

This is my attempt at an augmented matrix with two columns one for each of b1 and b2 in (i) and (ii) above.  Rows are indicated as r1 and r2 of each matrix to explain the row operations (sorry couldn't figure out MathJax square brackets).

$\begin{array}{[ccc c|c|}r_1 & 1 & -5 && 1 & -2
                     \\r_2 & 3 & 2 &&  4 & 5  \end{array}$

$ row op: r_2=-3r_1 + r_2 $

$\begin{array}{ccc c|c|}r_1 & 1 & -5 && 1 & -2
                     \\r_2 & 0 & 17 && 1 & 11\end{array}$

$ row op: r_2= (1/r_2) ( r_2 )$ did i just divide by $0$??

$\begin{array}{ccc c|c|}r_1 & 1 & -5 && 1 & -2
                     \\r_2 & 0 & 1 && 1 & \frac{1}{11}\end{array}$

$ row op: r_1= 5r_2 + r_1 $

$\begin{array}{ccc c|c|}r_1 & 1 & 0 && 6 & 3\frac{1}{11}
                     \\r_2 & 0 & 1 && 1 & \frac{1}{11}\end{array}$

So my answer for (i) is: $x_1=6, x_2=1$ and for (ii) is: $x_1= 3\frac{1}{11}, x_2=\frac{1}{11}$

But the answer that Anton gives for (i) is :

$ x_1 = \frac{22}{17}, x_2 = \frac{1}{17} $

and for (ii) is:

$ x_1=\frac{21}{17}, x_2=\frac{11}{17}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Using pictures to replace proper formatting is frowned upon here, so I've replaced it with a little [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). Also frowned upon is posting questions without including some of your own thoughts/attempts to solve the question for yourself, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/). Questions that don't include attempts may be down-voted and closed, and people who answer such questions [may be punished](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/).

Comment: Thank you for the advice and reformatting of my question.  I'll upload my attempt.

Comment: The second *rowop* should be $r_2=(1/17)r_2$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that worked @Gonçalo.  I'm falling in love with this community.  Btw, I accidentally clicked twice to upload your vote and I cannot now vote on it again to upvote it.  Some kind of restriction.